# Creating CACHE on single database - MySQL 

Tags: mysql, sql

Can i create cache on just a single database, not on all the databases ?
If yes, how to do it ?

```
set global query_cache_size=500000000;
```

As it is the SQL to create query on all the database i tried this

```
set 'DB_NAME' query_cache_size=500000000;
```

But failed !
can you help me on this ?

Comment: mysql does not support it, may be memcache can help u do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way to do that. Because when I check docs of related topic, it is said that query_cache_size is a system variable,  it affects globally, not for database. And if you want to make some database to use query cache, I advice you to optimize your sql instead.